# CSP warning firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug, content-security-policy

Im developing a game with JavaScript and canvas. And recently since i implemented clicks i have been receiving this message in firebug:

> CSP WARN:  allow directive is deprecated, use the equivalent default-source directive instead

Its not affecting the game at all, but i was wondering what it meant? and could it affect my game eventually?

I found this online, but i can't make any sense of it, and im not totally sure if its talking about the same message that im receiving

[LINK](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=634778)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSP is [Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/), these are HTTP headers that can for example restrict JavaScript execution in the browser. The warning points out a non-critical problem with the policy.

To look at the headers you could use `curl -I` on your server. The "Content-Security-Policy", "X-Content-Security-Policy" and "X-WebKit-CSP" fields are relevant.

Since you don't know about CSP I assume you are not administrating the web server, you might want to talk to the person in charge.

Comment: Im working on an XAMPP server so localhost, so where would i use curl -I on that? if you know haha. Also how would i stop this from happening? thanks

Comment: `curl -I http://<yourURL>` then. I don't know XAMPP, you would have to check the docs :-)

Comment: I just tried: curl -I http://localhost but just sent me to google haha, ill have a look at the docs, thanks anyway!

Comment: i didnt get one, where should i be running curl -I? browser or elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more verbose. curl is a command-line browser.

Comment: I don't think it comes pre-installed with Windows, my insights for that platform are pretty limited. But you could fetch a copy from here: http://curl.haxx.se/ alternatively, maybe use a traffic sniffer on your loopback device and look at the traffic to figure out what's going on with the webserver. But - if this is not your production server the CSP issue is probably not a big deal.

Comment: Just an FYI, it's default-src, not default-source. That is a display bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=832193 (I guess this hasn't been released)

Comment: You can open it up in Firefox, open firebug, and view the "net" tab. Same for chrome "network" tab. Look for "response headers"

Answer (score 1):

That is old syntax for CSP. You don't say: "allow 'self'" anymore. You say:

Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'